# Migrating complex core data model

Tags: cocoa, core-data

I have a couple of questions about core data model migration.

I have a pretty complex data model with a couple cases of entity inheritance. I was going to make some changes to the data model in a new version and try and setup migration but when it migrated the store I lost some of the data that belonged to an entity that inherited from another entity.

In my case I have a few entities that all inherit from a "Resource" entity. This resource entity has a attribute "name". When I try to migrate the data store all entities that inherit from the "Resource" entity lose their name.

Is their any way to get model migration working for a data model with inheritance? I have already shipped a beta and I need to make a couple of updates to the model but I obviously don't want the users to lose all of their data.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try "playing" on your new model with `Column properties > Versioning > Renaming identier`, entering the previous field name, which I guess is the same. I doubt that will work with inheritance, but that is worth the try... *(That not so documented feature, allowing to keep data across renames, saved me several times)*.

If that doesn't work, I'm afraid you have to do a "manual migration"... with Model mappings and other things... which is imho a bit complex. See Apple documentation on this topic... I then would suggest to just rollback your changes and forget inheritance, quicker & easier, even if it is less "clean". Or just assume your users will loose some data, at beta stage this is not so important... *(Or maybe you can just collect old data in memory/plist file before migrating model an then repopulate)*

Good luck! CoreData automatic model migration is great, but take care that it will work only with simple modifications...

---

Oh, just one another trick, add `-com.apple.CoreData.SQLDebug 1` to your app launch arguments, and you will get all sql requests generated by CoreData... That might help you to understand the migration process. *(and some other things...)*

Comment: I am fine attempting to use model mappings. I need them anyway to support leopard. But the problem is that even with model mappings it didn't seem to be working correctly. But I will try the suggestion about SQLDebug. Thanks